# NotesUIDocument and NotesDocument Send - one works, one doesn't but, never both

Tags: blackberry, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am working with a calendar and scheduling application.  The requirements are to work in Notes and on Blackberry devices.  Currently when I do a send using a NotesDocument, it works fine for the first meeting send on all.  However, if you update the meeting, it only sends a correct message to the Notes client.  The Blackberry will receive a rich text only e-mail.  All MIMEs are correct in sending as well.

Changing this to send using NotesUIDocument will work fine for all instances on the Blackberry but, in Notes gives the error:

*Part or all of this meeting is already on your calendar. You must decline those entries first before processing this notice.*

I'm kind of at a loss here because what works in one won't work in the other. I am using Notes 8.5.1 and BES 5.0.2.  Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a MailOptions field (computed to itself and set via code) to control a send on UI save? That's how mailing works reliably with web apps -- it seems to invoke some voodoo to which I am not privy to add all of the jots and tittles to the right messages to the right parts of the system.